# Does HQL select query = select *?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Recently I am dealing with HQL and come across a question: does a simple HQL select query = to a sql select * statement, especially in terms of performance?

E.g. Are the followings the same?

HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Person where name= :name");
query.setParameter("name", "Peter");
List list = query.list();
```

SQL:

```
Select * from Person where name = "Peter"
```

In case you are interested, I am use MS SQL Server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct both are same, However first time HQL will be slow but in next time onward will be much more faster as it already compiled and having required objects already is session. And yes that is the beauty of Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

There is one difference between two

**HQL:** Will keep results in cache, from second time you will get result from cache.

**SQL:** To run SQL you may use createSQLQuery() method. SQL query will not get result from cache and will hit database every time.